# SciFi book with man and woman traveling across planets in a three seater cycle, with their pet dog

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel, planets

I remember reading a SciFi book as a child! It involved a man and a woman, possibly sibilings traveling across different planets in a three seater cycle along with their pet dog! The book must be from the early 90s!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  There isn't a lot of detail here; you should check out the [guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for writing a good question to see if you can [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/204862/edit) anything else into your question.  For example, about what year was it?  (We don't know when you were a child.)

Comment: My only thought was it might be Dragonfall 5 and the Space Cowboys, https://www.amazon.co.uk/Dragonfall-Space-Cowboys-Brian-Earnshaw/dp/0688416802, but it's from 1975.